# SCRIPT7002: XMLHttpRequest: Network Error 0x2ef3

Tags: virtualbox

I am trying to access host nodejs server from virtual machine but keep getting this error.

```
SCRIPT7002: XMLHttpRequest: Network Error 0x2ef3, Could not complete the operation due to error 00002ef3.
```

Comment: Internet explorer error